# Pollution DataSet

Tags: data-request, usa, city, europe, environment

I am looking for any dataset for pollution (pollutant measurements co2, ozone, .. etc) at any city in US/Europe during 2014. Most of Datasets I found are old.

**UPDATE**

Datasets I found so far:

New York 1973: 
http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/datasets/html/airquality.html

http://wonder.cdc.gov/wonder/help/pm.html

Comment: Can you post details & links for the outdated datasets? That will help people not post redundant answers.

Comment: Thanks! @philshem posted + I found commercial APIs as well.

Answer (score 5):

The WHO provides global data for many cities. It doesn't seem to break down the overall air pollution into molecular components, though.

- [Website](http://www.who.int/phe/health_topics/outdoorair/databases/cities/en/) with details
- Ambient (outdoor) air pollution database, by country and city ([Excel](http://www.who.int/entity/quantifying_ehimpacts/national/countryprofile/aap_pm_database_may2014.xls?ua=1) file)

Many individual cities or regions provide air quality data. A short example, although basically every city or region will have some level of data or map available:

- Ontario, which can be filtered on only Toronto - http://www.airqualityontario.com/history/
- [London](http://www.londonair.org.uk/london/asp/datadownload.asp)

You may also find good data from the EPA (US) website:

- [Overview of data sets](http://www.epa.gov/air/airpolldata.html)
- There are several resources that have varying levels of details

---

Note that air pollution and greenhouse gases are different molecules and at different levels of the atmosphere. Air pollutants are often measured with PM (particular matter) sizes ([wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particulates))

> The composition of particulate matter that generally causes visual effects such as smog consists of sulfur dioxide, nitrogen oxides, carbon monoxide, mineral dust, organic matter, and elemental carbon also known as black carbon or soot.

If you are looking for only greenhouse gases, you may not find data with such accurate geolocation.